# how can i use database datas in the layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

in the asp.net when i used masterpages i can use masterpage code behind to run share codes .
in the MVC how can i do  it . all pages use layout.cshtml but there isn't any share controller .

in my layout i have some datas that must load from database but there isn't anywhere to write these code and fill viewbag to send data to layout.cshtml

```
<div class="page">
    <header  >
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Management</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="logindisplay">
            @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
        </div>
    <br />
    <br />
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                       // these data must load from db
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shared directory you put all your files (like master pages and partial views) that will be used across your web application, hopefully in a situation where they are used more than once (for partial views).  There is not a shared controller, but you could create a CommonController that can handle stuff like your menu.

I don't know what other data you need to display in your view, but looking at your example it seems like you want to display menu items in a ul tag.

I would have a class that would represent a menu item like:

```
public class MenuItem
{
     public int MenuId { get; set; }
     public string MenuName { get; set; }
}
```

I always create a view model for each view.  This is better because then you have only the fields that are required on the view.  Never send your domain objects to the view directly.

A view model would look something like this, it can contain many other properties, but for this demo I will only include the meu items.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     // This will contain the menu items that you want displayd in your view
     public IEnumerable<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

You action method (in a controller called something like CommonController):

```
public ActionResult MyActionMethod
{
     MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel
     {
          // Here you do a database call to populate your menu items
          // This GetAllMenuItems method returns a list of MenuItem objects
          MenuItems = menuItemService.GetAllMenuItems()
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

Create a partial view that will get its data from CommonController (you need to create this with the action method above).  Loop through each MenuItem in MenuItems and display the name in a li tag.

```
<ul>

     @foreach (var item in Model.MenuItems)
     {
          <li>item.MenuName</li>
     }

</ul>
```

I hope this helps.  The rest I leave up to you do the rest and read up on more articles.  There is many info on the internet that describes what you want to do.  You just need to invest in time to read these articles.

Comment: perfect, i was going about this completely the wrong way.

Comment: @Brendan you are saying one should use View model instead of Data Model then how should i proceed if i want to add data into DB using View Model because data can be saved only using Data model using Entity Framework. Correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options.  You can either use a partial view (with it's own controller and view model) or you can use a base controller.  With a base controller, each controller would use it as an ancestor and you can use the base controller to load common data elements.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I was having the same problem suddenly I got that we can easily access VB in Layout form using Razor I am working with vb. You can modify this code for c#. I am using `@Imports System.Data.SqlClient`. This code is working perfectly for me and I want exactly what you describe

```
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-indent"></i>
                        <span>Transaction</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>

                        <span class="label label-primary pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu scrollbar">
                        @Code
                            Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                                Dim sSql = "SELECT * FROM SM_OBJECT_INFO WHERE menu_name = 'Transaction' Order By group_index, index_no"
                                Dim formname As String
                                Dim formtitle As String
                                Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sSql, conn)
                                conn.Open()
                                Dim rst As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                                Do While rst.Read()
                                    formname = rst!form_name
                                    formtitle = rst!object_name
                                    @<li><a href=@formname>@formtitle</a></li>
                                Loop
                            End Using
                        end code
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea - opening a Database connection after we've exited the controller is error-prone and outside the normal error routes.  I don't believe MVC can re-route when the View fails to render, it just fails.  Badly.  And Db Stuff is error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

This article worked for me-- below i am writing in details-
In the shared directory you put all your files (like master pages and partial views) that will be used across your web application, hopefully in a situation where they are used more than once (for partial views).  There is not a shared controller, but you could create a CommonController that can handle stuff like your menu.

I don't know what other data you need to display in your view, but looking at your example it seems like you want to display menu items in a ul tag.

I would have a class that would represent a menu item like:

```
public class MenuItem
{
     public int MenuId { get; set; }
     public string MenuName { get; set; }
}
```

I always create a view model for each view.  This is better because then you have only the fields that are required on the view.  Never send your domain objects to the view directly.

A view model would look something like this, it can contain many other properties, but for this demo I will only include the meu items.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     // This will contain the menu items that you want displayd in your view
     public IEnumerable<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

You action method (in a controller called something like CommonController):

```
public ActionResult MyActionMethod
{
     MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel
     {
          // Here you do a database call to populate your menu items
          // This GetAllMenuItems method returns a list of MenuItem objects
          MenuItems = menuItemService.GetAllMenuItems()
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

Create a partial view that will get its data from CommonController (you need to create this with the action method above).  Loop through each MenuItem in MenuItems and display the name in a li tag.

```
<ul>

     @foreach (var item in Model.MenuItems)
     {
          <li>item.MenuName</li>
     }

</ul>
```

I hope this helps.  The rest I leave up to you do the rest and read up on more articles.  There is many info on the internet that describes what you want to do.  You just need to invest in time to read these articles.

---

This is very useful article to achieve asp.net master page functionality in MVC. i.e. if we want a functionality which is common for every page[ every controller/view in MVC] need to follow this article steps. 
I faced once problem which is not mentioned in this article going to share below-
When we will create partial view which will be called on _layout page for being share in every view.. we hare to write -
    @{Html.RenderAction("BindMenu", "Common");} 
on _Layout page.
Since I was newbie and i wast trying to call partial view like-
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_HeaderMenuPartial.cshtml", Model.MenuItemsList)
which was not working.